How to connect to PostgreSQL DB on PythonAnywhere?
I uploaded a site that is the basic Django "Hello World" site with a few changes.  For one thing, the DB is configured to use Postgres.  This works fine locally but I am having trouble understanding how to complete the setup on PythonAnywhere.
On PA the DB was set up using psql as follows:
CREATE DATABASE domain_db;

CREATE USER domain_admin WITH PASSWORD '123456789';

\connect domain_db;

CREATE SCHEMA domain_schema AUTHORIZATION domain_admin;

-- Settings recommended by Django documentation
ALTER ROLE domain_admin SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
ALTER ROLE domain_admin SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
ALTER ROLE domain_admin SET timezone TO 'UTC';

Note that this approach is based on recommendations due to changes to Postgres permissions changes with v15 (which is what we are using locally).  I am assuming that this works with v12, which is what I think PA is using.  Could be wrong on that.
https://gist.github.com/axelbdt/74898d80ceee51b69a16b575345e8457
https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/error-permission-denied-schema-public/
The project directory structure looks like this:
domain/
    site/
        _config/
            settings/
                base.py           Settings common to local and production
                local.py          Local development settings
                production.py     Production server settings
            asgi.py
            urls.py
            wsgi.py
        staticfiles/
        manage.py
    venv
    .env

In base.py I configure the database using environment variables loaded from the .env file.  I have confirmed that the .env file is being loaded and environment variables set according to its contents.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
...
env = environ.Env()
env_file_path = BASE_DIR.parent / ".env"
env.read_env(env_file_path)
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": env("ENGINE"),
        "OPTIONS": env.json("OPTIONS", default={}),
        "NAME": env("NAME"),
        "USER": env("USER"),
        "PASSWORD": env("PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": env("HOST"),
        "PORT": env("PORT"),
    }
}

Relevant portions of the .env file (data changed for this post):
ALLOWED_HOSTS=www.<domain>.com,<domain>.com

# Database
ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
OPTIONS={"options": "-c search_path=domain_schema"}
NAME=domain_db
USER=domain_admin
PASSWORD=123456789
HOST=<prefix>.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com
PORT=<port provided by PA>

When I try to run makemigrations, I get the following error (edited):
/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:160: 

RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default':

connection failed: connection to server at "xx.xx.xx.xx", port <xxxxx> failed:

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user <user> connection to server at "xx.xx.xx.xx.", port <xxxxx> failed:

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user <user>

I have confirmed the connection using:
psql -h <prefix>.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com -U domain_admin -d domain_db -p <port>

Not really sure where to go from here.  I think the settings in .env are correct.  Is there something else I have to setup to make this work?  Or, is it a case of Postgres v12 needing a very different configuration with respect to what we are using locally (v15).  If so, is there a way to upgrade to v15 in order to match our production to local?


I'm not sure what  the point of the settings are, much less what they have to do with permissions changes. read_committed is the default transaction level. As to client_encoding and timezone those can be changed at will anyway. 2) The issue is password authentication failed. That means either you are using the wrong password string or password type. Since the default password type changed from md5 in 12 to scram-sha-256 in 15, I betting it is this. Look at the Postgres log to see a more error message.


Regarding the settings.  I am obviously not a Postgres expert.  I am simply providing full information here.  I followed the recommendation of the experts (see links).  I will check logs and see what I might discover.  That said, I can login to the database with psql using exactly the same credentials from the .env file.

Consider adding some debugging logs to your settings to make sure that the values are passed correctly from your env file to the settings as you expect.

JSYK PostgreSQL on Pythonanywhere is reserved for only paid users so I'm guessing you're not using a free account.
